# MySQL error declaring a FLOAT(10,6)

Tags: mysql, database, procedure

I have an error on the line 5, not sure what the error is. The overall effect of the procedure will create Trees and building within a set square radius of current players lat lng. If there is any other errors after this I'll be grateful if you could point these out as well.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PupulateLatLng(lat FLOAT(10,6), lng FLOAT(10,6), radius INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE mlat FLOAT(10,6);
        SET mlat = 0.00084;
        DECLARE mlng FLOAT(10,6);
        SET mlng = 0.00118;
        DECLARE scope FLOAT(10,6);
        SET scope = Floor(radius/100);
        DECLARE baselat FLOAT(10,6);
        SET baselat = Floor(lat/mlat) * mlat;
        DECLARE baselng FLOAT(10,6);
        SET baselng = Floor(lng/mlng) * mlng;
        DECLARE dlat FLOAT(10,6);
        DECLARE dlng FLOAT(10,6);
        DECLARE dlatunits INT;
        SET dlatunits = -scope;
        loop1: LOOP
          SET dlatunits = dlatunits + 1;
              DECLARE dlngunits INT;
              SET dlngunits = -scope;
              loop2: LOOP
                  SET dlngunits = dlngunits + 1;
                  dlat = dlatunits * mlat;
                  dlng = dlngunits * mlat;
                  DECLARE rand FLOAT(10,6);
                  SET rand = rand();
                  IF (rand <= 0.3) THEN
                    GenerateTree(Floor((lat + dlat)*1000000)/1000000, Floor((lng + dlng)*1000000)/1000000);
                  ELSEIF (rand <= 0.4) THEN
                    GenerateNPCBuilding(Floor((lat + dlat)*1000000)/1000000, Floor((lng + dlng)*1000000)/1000000);            
                IF dlngunits < scope THEN
                  ITERATE loop2;
                END IF;
                LEAVE loop2;
              END LOOP loop2;
          IF dlatunits < scope THEN
            ITERATE loop1;
          END IF;
          LEAVE loop1;
        END LOOP loop1;
    END
```

Comment: Pls do not edit the answer into the question because the question will not make any sense after that.

Answer (score 0):

The `declare` statements must come [before any other statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) in the compound statement syntax within a `begin` - `end` block. Since you mix `declare` with `set`, you get an error message for the 2nd `declare`.

The correct syntax is to have all declares at the top:

```
    ...
    DECLARE mlat FLOAT(10,6);
    DECLARE mlng FLOAT(10,6);
    DECLARE scope FLOAT(10,6);
    DECLARE baselat FLOAT(10,6);
    DECLARE baselng FLOAT(10,6);
    DECLARE dlat FLOAT(10,6);
    DECLARE dlng FLOAT(10,6);
    DECLARE dlatunits INT;
    SET mlat = 0.00084;
    SET mlng = 0.00118;
    SET scope = Floor(radius/100);
    SET baselat = Floor(lat/mlat) * mlat;
    SET baselng = Floor(lng/mlng) * mlng;
    SET dlatunits = -scope;
    ...
```

Or alternatively, you can use the `default` clause of the `declare` statement to assign a default value to a variable without the need of an extra `set`:

```
DECLARE mlat FLOAT(10,6) DEFAULT 0.00084;
```

Comment: I have updated the code but now showing error on line 32??

Comment: If you have any follow-up questions, then pls ask them in their own, separate question, properly indicating the error message.